# Soft keyboard does not show when Activity starts

Tags: android, user-interface, soft-keyboard

I have added `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"` to my Activity in **AndroidManifest.xml** and here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/EditText02" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></EditText>
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Send"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

[alt text http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/2006/18021414.png](http://img227.imageshack.us/img227/2006/18021414.png)

When the Activity starts, the EditText is focused, but soft keyboard isn't displayed. If I click on the EditText, then I see the soft keyboard. Do I need to set aditional parameters to display soft keyboard when my Activity starts?

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

### solution 1 :

write following code inside onCreate() method of activity

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)
    SearchActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

if (imm != null){
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);
}
```

### solution 2 :

create following method and call from onCreate()

```
private void showVirturalKeyboard(){
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
              InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) SearchActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

              if(m != null){
                // m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                m.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
              } 
         }

    }, 100);         
}
```

Comment: Not sure why, but solution 2 works for me if I increase the delay to 200 or more milliseconds on my Galaxy Nexus.  I have my activity's windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible", hide the keyboard while showing an indeterminate dialog, then attempt to re-show it.

Answer (score 7):

Try adding this to the activities onCreate() method

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Have you tried not setting it at all? I had the opposite problem, I didn't want the soft keyboard to appear when the screen showed first but it semed to be the default setting that it did